# Sampling production database - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I have a PostgreSQL RDS that is running on AWS. I would like to sample this database to create a "similar" production environment. Is there any tool that can handle this? Or do I need to built it?

I would prefer some solution in python.

Comment: if you jave owners credentials, try pg_dump

Comment: or maybe AWS DMS?..